# Font awesome gradient animation on hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

When a icon font awesome is hovered, I want the color gradient to animate.

I have tried the following code but is not working:

Code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exoQmp

What is wrong with my code?

```
.awesome-gradient {

    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, red, blue);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

  &:hover {
  animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes gradient {
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

I followed and referenced a button tutorial but not applying to the icons.

Comment: For one, your CodePen settings are wrong. You've written `SCSS` but don't have it enabled in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate a `background: linear-gradient(...` is basically the same than trying to animate a background-image by playing with its position, which mostly ends in unwanted flickering issues.

Instead, **you can have two backgrounds and swap them on hover via `opacity`**.
Notice in the example I've used a mixin for reusing it (inserts an `:after` pseudoelement and supports a `$content` parameter so you can provide the FontAwesome icon code).

See it here: https://codepen.io/cdtapay/pen/NommGN